# filter price range by django-filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I added a price range filter by Django-filter but seems it doesn't work.

filters.py

```py
from django_filters import FilterSet
from .models import Apartment

class ApartmentFilter(FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Apartment
        fields = {
            'price': ['lt','gt']
        }
```

views.py

```py
class ApartmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Apartment.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = ApartmentSerializer
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerApartmentOrReadOnly]

    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter,
                       DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter]
    filter_class = ApartmentFilter
    search_fields = ['address']
    filterset_fields = ['category', 'district']
    ordering_fields = ('price',)
```

Comment: I think you can either use filterset_fields or filter_class. If you are using filter_class so define your filterset_fields inside your custom filter class. And if you are using model fields filter use filterset_fields not filter_class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use built-in [`RangeFilter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#rangefilter):

```
from django_filters import FilterSet, RangeFilter


class ApartmentFilter(FilterSet):
    price = RangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = Apartment
        fields = ['price']
```

Then, in your request parameters send it as `price_min` and `price_max`.

E.g. `<your_api_endpoint>/?price_min=100&price_max=200`

Comment: still does not working, cant I edit something in views?

Comment: @HuyNguyen yes, set the `filterset_class = ApartmentFilter` attribute in your class, not `filter_class` ;)

Comment: Thank you, It works, but seem it overrides other filters in my views!

Comment: @HuyNguyen simply add those fields in `filterset_fields` into your `ApartmentFilter`

Answer (score 1):

```
class ApartmentFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    min_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='gt')
    max_price = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr='lt')
    class Meta:
        model = Apartment
        fields = ['category', 'district']

class ApartmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Apartment.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    serializer_class = ApartmentSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerApartmentOrReadOnly]
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter, DjangoFilterBackend, filters.OrderingFilter]
    filter_class = ApartmentFilter
    search_fields = ['address']
```

More on documentation [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html)